# How to "undeclare" a function prototype or hide a function prototype or #uninclude a header

Tags: c, include, header-files, c-preprocessor

I would like to have function `A()` call `B()` as an inline macro, but I don't want `B()` to be visible to the world. I only want `A()` visible and if the user uses `B()` accidentally, I want a compiler error.

I know how to do it without inlining:

```
// a.h
void A(void);

// a.c
#include "b.h"
void A(void) { B(); }
```

If I `#include "a.h"`, then I have access to `A()` but not `B()`. That's fine; that's what I want.

Now I want to do the same, but reduce one level of call complexity by inlining `B` into `A`, but I want to hide `B`.

```
// a.h
#include "b.h"
#define A() B()
#uninclude "b.h"   <----This is bogus, but I want the equivalent.


// main.c
#include "a.h"
A();  <-- ok
B();  <-- undefined function
```

This is for low-level firmware, where the call overhead does make a difference but I don't want to abandon high-level code management just for efficiency.  In C++, this is trivial, but I am looking for `cpp` hacks to do it in pure C.

(In my case, `a` represents a HAL and `b` represents a BSP. The HAL is processor specific, while the BSP is board (PCB) specific)

Comment: You know about #undef, right?

Comment: It seems to me that "high-level code management" and "cpp hacks" are mutually exclusive. In general, you can't get the C compiler to stop a developer who is determined to ignore internal documentation; that's what code reviews are for.

Comment: @CharlieBurns -- I know about #undef, but how do you use it in this case? I can't `#undef A`.

Comment: @MarkLakata, Sorry I think I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only declaration `b.h` makes is a declaration of `B` and not a definition, then you can do this in `a.h`:

```
// a.h
static inline void A(void)
{
    #undef _B__H_  //need this if you have more than one of these inline declarations
    #include "b.h"
    B();
}
```

assuming `b.h` looks like this:

```
// b.h
#ifndef _B_H_
#define _B_H_
void B(void);
#endif
```

Then the declaration of `B` is in scope only within `A`.

In `a.c`, be sure to include `b.h` *before* `a.h` (or do `#undef _B_H_` to force reloading `b.h`). Otherwise, you will get warnings or errors about incompatible scopes. (`a.h` includes `b.h` at local scope, while `a.c` includes `b.h` at file scope then ignores all of the remaining local scope includes.)

This will also work if `b.h` makes additional declarations, as long as they are acceptable in the scope of a function body.

Comment: There is a caveat for this, I think, that if `b.h` includes (directly or indirectly) any system headers, then it is undefined behaviour to `#include` those files at function scope; they can only be included at file scope.  You're OK if those system headers were first included at file scope, but ensuring that might be tricky.

Comment: This didn't work out of box, because I have other non-inline functions in `b.h` that can't be included from `a.c` (file level) without giving me scope warnings.

Comment: That’s a shame, because this is the cleanest if `b.h` is suitable, since it does not play preprocessor games and leaves the name spaces clean. Perhaps it would be worth making a separate `bClean.h` that just declares `B`. But I expect `B` requires types for parameters or return value that are not shown in the question.

Comment: I found a workaround to make this the best solution and updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you do this:

```
#define B A
#include "b.h"
#undef B
```

This changes the definition of `B` in "b.h" to be a definition of `A` instead. This requires that `b.h` define `B`, not just declare it, so that might not be what you want.

Then after that, in the file where those lines appear, code can use `A` (with calls such as `A()`), but no declaration of `B` is in scope. So attempts to use `B` would result in compiler errors. (Other declarations made in `b.h` would be in scope.)

Comment: This sort of works for the limited case, but I have other functions in `B`space that I don't want to automatically rename to `A`space. I want `a.h` to decide what gets inlined. I'll still give +1 because it might be useful in other situations.

Answer (score 1):

```
#define A() (B)()
#define B() syntax error
```

People who write `B()` will get a syntax error reported (in some shape or form).
People who write `A()` will generate a call to `(B)()`, which is OK.

This does not stop someone writing `(B)()` in the code, of course, but it is 80% of the way there.

Comment: Neat trick. It is 99% of the way there for me... Someone could also use `#include "b.h"` to get around this as well, so if they are doing `(B)()` to get around it, they are just being spiteful.

Comment: There's one problem/feature that this generates. In my case, it is a feature.  It might be a problem for others. You can't include `a.h` in `b.c` now. This enforces the reference tree that `a` depends on `b`, but `b` does not depend on `a`.

Comment: There are ways around that; it depends on whether you want to use them.  One way is to have the code in `b.c` define something which means that `a.h` does not do the redefinition.